# Can Google Drive be deleted from a Samsung Galaxy Express?

Tags: delete, google-drive

I have a Samsung Galaxy Express phone running Android 4.1.2

Is there a way to delete Google Drive from the phone [without rooting it]? In the Application Manager, there is no DELETE button for Drive. The only buttons are to FORCE STOP and UNINSTALL UPDATES.

Comment: Sorry, apart form rooting it/installing a custom ROM, there is no way to remove system apps. You can, however, try to uninstall all updates and see, whether you are able to deactivate it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "delete" Google Drive without rooting the device, but you can at least disable the app or force stop it which is like deleting it except that you will ***not*** get the disk space that the app is using up back.

Answer (score 0):

I don't beleive so. Drive (I beleive), along with Gmail, Maps, etc is a required app that Samsung must include with their phones, and it can't be uninstalled - at least not easily without the likes of rooting.

Comment: You're right, but no need for "believing" here, Nucleotide – the matter is pretty clear: If you see a button labeled "uninstall updates", that's a system app which you cannot remove without root powers (user-installed apps never have that "uninstall updates").

Answer (score -1):

If you see a button labeled "uninstall updates", that's a system app which you cannot remove without root powers. User-installed apps never have that "uninstall updates" button, for a simple technical reason:

- a "system app" has its original `.apk` file installed on the `/system` partition, which is mounted read-only. If it receives an update, it thus cannot simply replace its original `.apk` – so the update gets placed on the `/data` partition (along with the user-installed apps).
- a user-installed app gets installed straight on `/data` – so if there's an update, it replaces the originally installed `.apk`.

Hence, by the simple existence of a button labeled "uninstall updates" you can tell that's a system app. You then can push that button: after uninstalling updates, in most cases it changes its lable to "disable". Push that button again, and the app is "disabled" – i.e. doesn't turn up in your app drawer, on your homescreen, or anywhere else except for *Settings › Apps* (where you could re-enable it when needed). That's the closest you can come to uninstalling without rooting your device.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to explain what's wrong with this answer? I'm always willing to consider critics and learn from them – but for that I need facts :)